# Why is creating a set from a filter so much faster than creating a list or a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

I’m running `filter` on an interable and want to store the result in a sequence (I need a sequence so that I can use `random.choice` on it). I noticed that creating a *set* from a *filter* object is a lot faster than creating a *list* or a *tuple*. Why is that? I first though that the filter type is a subtype of set, which would explain this, but the `filter` function is actually identical to a generator expression, so it cannot really be a set internally.

I ran the following test to check the speed:

```
import time

def test ( n, seq ):
    for method in ( set, list, tuple ):
        t = time.time()
        for i in range( n ):
            method( seq )
        print( method.__name__, ( time.time() - t ) )

someFilter = filter( lambda x: x % 3 == 0, range( 1000 ) )
test( 10000000, someFilter )
```

And the results were speaking clearly for using a set:

```
set 1.9240000247955322
list 8.82200002670288
tuple 7.031999826431274
```

So why is creating a set from a filter so much faster? Shouldn’t it usually take as long as creating a set from a sequence, where every element has to be hashed? Or is it somehow getting a boost from the internal filter representation?

For comparison, when running the test on a `range` expression, `set` takes about twice as long as `list` and `tuple` (which are both nearly identical in speed).

#### edit:

Sven’s answer is totally right, but for the completeness an updated test that will run on an actual filter:

```
import time

def testFilter ( n, test, rangeSize ):
    for method in ( set, list, tuple ):
        t = time.time()
        for i in range( n ):
            method( filter( test, range( rangeSize ) ) )
        print( method.__name__, ( time.time() - t ) )

testFilter( 100000, lambda x: x % 3 == 0, 1000 )
```

The result actually shows what makes more sense with `list` and `tuple` both being the fastest, although set isn’t really slower, so it won’t make any difference what to use:

```
set 27.868000030517578
list 27.131999969482422
tuple 27.138000011444092
```

Comment: Using `timeit.timeit` would be easier.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Yeah, I know, but I keep forgetting how to use it, so I always end up making such small testers myself ^^

Comment: @Chris: I disagree. `timeit` can be easier for one-shot, one-line, throw-away tests done at the command line. But if you're going to write a small program (maybe you don't know *exactly* what you're going to test yet, maybe you will want to modify it or add to it or reuse it) then doing it as shown in the question is at least as easy as `timeit` and maybe easier. Also, it is completely intuitive to use clock readings to measure time, whereas I actually have to consult the docs to remember how to use `timeit`, especially if setup is involved.

Comment: Oops.  I guess I need to refresh more often.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`filter()` returns an iterator in Python 3, and this iterator will be consumed on the first run of the inner for-loop.  After that, you are only measuring the speed of the contructor -- that's why you have to repeat it so often to make it consume at least a bit of time.

So it seems that the constructor of `set()` is the fastest one in dealing with an empty iterator.

Comment: Ouch, yeah, that makes totally sense. What a stupid mistake! Thanks a lot for pointing it out! :)

Comment: Relative timings in 2.7, where filter is not a generator are set = 1.5767, list = 0.1468, tuple = 0.1556

Comment: `filter` actually already returns a list in Python 2, so that explains the speed ;)

Answer (score 4):

When timings suggest results that are illogical, often it is the timing suite itself that is at fault ;-)

Try using the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) which can help steer you clear of common timing mistakes.  In particular, you want to run a fresh *setup* for each test and only time the loop body rather than the body plus the test code.

In this case, it would have at least made the timings comparable (all of them would have used a fresh iterator as returned by Python 3's version of *filter) and it would have shown unbelievably fast timings (because only the `method(iterator)` code would have been timed in a loop).

FWIW, *pypy* will be even harder to time because overly simple loops get optimized away completely.

[Answer to the question as edited] You new timings are comparable (a good improvement) but the results still show the combination of the setup time and the loop time making it difficult to see differences that might be significant.   Your expectation should be that lists and tuples beat sets because sets have to do more work (hashing each of the inputs rather than simply storing them).

Comment: Yeah, you’re right, but with Python you never know if it is really illogical, or just some awesome hidden language feature :D

Comment: Guess I’ll really have to invest some more time into the timeit module then to finally get it inside my head for the next time. Thanks for your explanations!